# Is it possible to use a car's Bluetooth speaker for noise cancelling?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, bluetooth, noise

I thought about it one day while using anc earphones.

Earphones almost suppressed the noise of the car.

Meanwhile, I wondered if anc using car speakers and mobile phone applications would be possible.

It would be difficult to respond immediately to changes in sound, but I thought that continuous noise would be sufficient to solve.

The application is to continuously analyze the sound coming into the microphone, find the Bluetooth latency, find the frequency at which the noise is reduced, and reduce the noise.

I searched for projects in GitHub, but I couldn't find them, and my goal is to find them or for me to start a project like that.

Question:

1. If this is impossible, why?
2. If this is possible, would there be such a project?
3. What are the techniques for making this?

If there's nothing, I'm going to try a project with an android or web app :)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: This feels like an invitation to a discussion rather than a concrete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that this is almost impossible.

If you want to do something like this, you would have to start with a clibration phase. The speakers would hae to send some calibration audio, so that the wavelengths can come to you ear perfectly. Also cars usually have no build in multi surround audio with bluetooth so you would only get stereo in your car, making things more difficult.

After sesnigna nd calibrating you would have o have a continous loop of measuring and sending data to get the noiseprint. For that you would have to have the microphones as close to your ear as possible, to capture the excact noise you are hearing. Also the microphones had to be quite good to capture in a high quality.

Factoring in all those problems, it is as I said "almost impossible" to do so.